# Is it possible to draw coloured lines in Photoshop (CS6) with the pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I'd like to draw over a photo in a new layer with the pen tool.

When I do this, the path created has no colour.

Do I need to use the Pixels option with the path tool?

Deselecting that path, then using the pen tool again, there is a drop-down in the toolbar to select shape/path/pixels. Pixels is greyed out, the other two are not.

https://youtu.be/ZiR5BhizmWI

FTR, I found Fireworks CS6's pen tool is exactly what I was after, I'm very thankful I have a copy of CS6 but would love to know how to produce something similar in Photoshop CS6; I'd like to use Photoshop CS6 for painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop CS6 or newer...

Set the Pen Tool options to `Shape` in the **Control Bar**, then adjust the fill/stroke so there's only a stroke color.

Then draw.....

[image]